# Get value of specific attribute via XPath

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I'm looking to extract some data of a website using XPath with PHP. Here is an example of page: http://www.education.gouv.fr/annuaire/49-maine-et-loire/cholet/lycee/lycee-polyvalent-europe-robert-schuman.html

I managed to get different informations I was looking for except one. The href attribute of the "Site Internet" link (the third link of three in the middle of the page).

The Xpath of this node is :

```
//*[@id="contenu"]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[5]/ul/li[3]/a
```

And I know that to get the value of an attribute we need to add @attribute, so I tried:

```
//*[@id="contenu"]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[5]/ul/li[3]/a@href
```

But it doesn't work, it's just showing me the text "Site internet".
Can you help me please ? Thanks.

Comment: `//*[@id="contenu"]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[5]/ul/li[3]/a/@href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the href value of a link, it's **`a/@href`**.

So your query would then be:

`//*[@id="contenu"]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[5]/ul/li[3]/a/@href`